# Batch file to edit multiple .txt files

Tags: batch-file, text-files, batch-processing

I have over 1300 .txt files where I need to edit the first line of text, replacing one name for another. Can someone please advise of the best way to achieve this?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Stu

Comment: For a windows solution, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/how-can-you-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-the-windows-command-line-envir

Answer (score 0):

If this is Linux, then sed is the answer.

Comment: Thanks I am on Windows, not Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Use [sed](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html). Here's a simple one-liner that would do what you want:

```
sed -i '1s/oldtext/newtext/' *.txt
```

The `-i` tells sed to edit the files in-place. The `1` at the beginning of the pattern applies it only to the first line. The `s//` constrution replaces the text.

Comment: Keep in mind that sed is available on windows through Cygwin: http://www.cygwin.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -npi~ -e "s/old/new/g" file.txt
```

If you're on a Windows machine, install [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/).

Comment: I am downloading Strawberry Perl, so I'll give it try. Thank you for your reply!!!